# Selenium 4.6 not using correct version of ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So i'm try to get Selenium to work but i'm encountering a problem with ChromeDriver. I'm using Selenium v4.6 i have Chrome version 115.0.5790.171. I know that version 4.6 has Selenium Manager fully integrated with Selenium and can silently download the matching ChromeDriver but in my case i'm still getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 101 Current browser version is 115.0.5790.171 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Here is an example of a scraper that i built:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time

custom_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
custom_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})

service = Service()
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://lr.caa.cz/letecky-rejstrik?lang=en")

data = []

while True:
    try:
        print("Page source:")
        print(driver.page_source)
        print("Waiting for table rows to load...")
        rows_length = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr"))))
        print(f"Found {rows_length} rows")
        for i in range(rows_length):
            row_data = []
            print("Waiting for table data to load...")
            table_data = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, f"//tbody/tr[{i+1}]/td")))
            for j in table_data:
                row_data.append(j.text.strip())
            data.append(row_data)
            print(row_data)
        next_button = None
        try:
            print("Trying to find next button...")
            next_button = driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/app-root/div/main/div/div/app-avreg-list/nav/div/app-pagination/div/a[3]')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error finding next button: {e}")
            break
        if not next_button:
            print("Next button not found")
            break
        try:
            if "disabled" in next_button.get_attribute("class"):
                print("Next button is disabled")
                break
            print("Clicking next button")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error clicking next button: {e}")
            break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        break

print(f"Collected {len(data)} rows of data")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("CZ register.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

The only way to get around this is to have ChromeDriver installed locally on my machine and change the script with the following lines:

```
#path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'  
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(path_to_chromedriver), options=custom_options)
```

What i want to know is if there is a way of resolving this issue without having the script point to a local version of ChromeDriver rather it silently download the matching ChromeDriver without it giving an error that there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this path in your local machine, and you may find `chromedriver` version `101` there. Just delete it. And delete any other versions which you see. After that when you run your code, selenium should download `v115` driver and place it here. And then it should start using `v115` driver.

[image]

**References:** [What's new in Selenium Manager with Selenium 4.11.0](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/whats-new-in-selenium-manager-with-selenium-4.11.0/)

[image]